# Rough start, started after getting gas one day. (Not a full tank)

Tags: starting, nissan, gasoline, pathfinder

I drive a 2000 pathfinder. A few weeks ago I grabbed a couple gallons of gas from a place down the street because it was late and my usual spot was closed. Since then its been rough starting up. I can hear the starter but it takes several clicks for the engine to actually turn.

It seemed to improve after I filled up from my usual place & drove a while. But, it still takes an extra second or two to start. I regularly go to the down-the-street place for a few gallons to hold me over but I've never had this issue before. I dont know if this matters but their truck was there to restock the station as I got my gas.

Calling mechanic today to make an appointment for new tires & oil change so I'll talk to him about it, but just wondered if anyone has any insight. I try not to go in blind. I think I'll get some fuel injector cleaner but it just seems strange that this happened so suddenly, right after I got gas at this place. When i tried to find info online i mostly just  found issues with starting on a full tank, which is not my experience. The issue persists whether full or near empty. Battery was replaced maybe 1.5-2 yr ago. I think i had spark plugs done about 1 yr ago.

The place in question is an Exxon now but they changed hands several times in the past year or two and I don't recall if they were already Exxon when this occured. We all still call it Noco even though it hasn't been that for some time  But it's not some sketchy place it's in the middle of a suburb and gets a decent amount of business. But I'm the only one in my circle that goes here with any frequency so I have no one to compare experience to.

If anyone has insight as to what might be causing this issue, please let me know! Am I crazy for thinking their gas mightve just been bottom of the barrel bunk that night? If thats the case, shouldn't it be improved by now since i filled up at my usual place? What else might I be missing?

Comment: It's hard to say but getting a batch of "dirty" gasoline is not unheard of.  It can clog the fuel filter and cause problems starting and running smoothly.  It's possible your 2000 had a dirty fuel filter to begin with and the latest batch just finished it off.

Comment: Getting gas at a gas station while a tanker is filling the tanks does make a difference. The fuel is stirring moisture and sediment in the tank. I've seen a few people have "bad gas" when a tanker is there. I always avoid it if there's a tanker present.